# simple numpy example from manual does not work as expected

Tags: numpy

The following code is from the Numpy 1.4.1 manual, [numpy.char](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.4.x/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html#numpy.chararray)

```
import numpy as np
charar = np.chararray((3, 3))
charar[:, :] = 'abc'
print charar
```

According to the manual, this is supposed to output

```
chararray([['a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['a', 'a', 'a']],
      dtype='|S1')
```

Instead I get

```
[['\xd8' '3' 'U']
 ['\xb7' '\x18' '\xc2']
 ['\xbd' '' '\x10']]
```

This looks like uninitialized values. Does anyone have any ideas what is going on here? I'm using the numpy package for Debian squeeze, which I realise is out of date, but I'm having some problems backporting the 1.6 package from unstable.

UPDATE: I've now backported the 1.6 package from unstable, minus the docs, which won't build for some reason. I get exactly the same results. I guess I'll go ahead and report this to the numpy project.

Comment: Are you sure that the assignment statement is getting executed? What happens if you do something like `charar.fill('b')` then print out the array?

Comment: @talonmies: Yes, I'm sure that the assignment statement is getting executed. :-) charar.fill('b') does give an array of 'b''s. Do you have a documentation link for this method? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have numpy 1.4 installed on my machine, but certainly if I run the code you wrote, I get a similar answer that doesn't match the manual. It should be noted though that in the newest version of the numpy manual the example has changed:

```
>>> charar = np.chararray((3, 3))
>>> charar[:] = 'a'
>>> charar
chararray([['a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['a', 'a', 'a']],
      dtype='|S1')
```

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html

Also, `np.chararray` post v1.4 is only included in numpy for backward compatibility with Numarray, and the manual states that it shouldn't be used for new development.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for the helpful comment. The example I quoted is still there in the reference you quote, just scroll down. Also, this documentation is for the dev version I think. I would prefer to look at the 1.6 docs. I just manged to upgrade to 1.6 and the behavior is unchanged. In any case, I guess I should report this. (BTW, the numpy manual is quite confusing about this char array stuff. They have a plethora of constructors.)

Comment: Hi Faheem, it looks like the dev version of the docs is identical to the official v1.6 ones: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html

Comment: Yes, so it is. Issue reported, btw.